# How do I launch "com.android.settings.Settings$VpnSettingsActivity" via adb

Tags: android, adb

I tried to use 
`adb shell am start com.android.settings/.Settings$VpnSettingsActivity`
to launch vpn activity. But it just launched com.android.settings.Settings.
Could any method launch the activity via adb?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to escape or single-quote the `$` character:

```
adb shell "am start -n 'com.android.settings/.Settings$VpnSettingsActivity'"
```

Comment: Thanks for help.
It's really helpful.

Comment: In that case will be like: **adb shell am start -n 'com.android.settings/.Settings\$VpnSettingsActivity'**